# Пошаговое выполнение кода в Visual studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Возможно ли и как в VSCode сделать пошаговое выполнение кода с просмотром значений в переменных как на этом сайте?
https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display

Comment: Ставьте точку останова в начале программы (красную точку слева от номеров строк), запускайте в режиме отладки, дальше от точки останова выполняйте с помощью F8/F7 (пошагово без входа в функции или со входом) или через соответствующие кнопки в панели отладки: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxKWL.png

Comment: P.S. если установлено расширение Code Runner - удалите или просто отключите, запуск через него с отладкой не возможен, запускайте через расширение Python от Microsoft ([ms-python.python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python)).